# Python Selenium strange ElementNotVisible Exception

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting a counter-intuitive ElementNotVisible Exception in Selenium. I am trying to rule out whether it's something with my approach or the website.

To explain, I want to click on a button 'Issue'. Before that, I have to choose between one of two tabs: 'Credit card', 'Transaction Limit'. So the code I'm using is as follows:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Credit card')]").click();
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Issue')]").click();
```

This piece of code works fine. However, when I change to:

```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Transaction Limit')]").click();
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Issue')]").click();
```

it throws an ElementNotVisible Exception if it tries to click on the 'Issue' button. I've tried multiple things, such as specifying the full XPath. But I can't seem to click on the Issue button if I click on Transaction Limit first. Does somebody else have any ideas that could solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Update the question with the relevant html

Comment: Credit card fields are generally made in iframe. Though does not look like in your case ? have you tried explicit wait?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
transaction  = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Transaction Limit')]")))  
transaction.click();   
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Issue')]").click();
```

OR

```
    transaction  = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Transaction Limit')]")))  
    transaction.click();   
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Issue')]").click();
```

Importing statement will look like this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! In my original code, I did add waits, but it doesn't solve the problem. It seems that I can only click the Issue button if I choose Credit Card. Do you know if I can identify such conditional dependencies in the html code?